# Angular 2 make form invalid

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-forms, jmespath

I have the following example code:

**component.html**

```
<form onsubmit="" #VoucherForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="field1" [(ngModel)]="rule['condition']"
  (ngModelChange)="validateJMES($event)">     
<form>
```

**component.ts**

```
validateJMES(value){
  try {
     this.jmespath.search({ }, value);
  } catch (e) {
     // Code that makes Form invalid
  }
}
```

So basicly i check if the input on the textfield is a valid `json` expression.
If i catch an error i would like to make the form invalid.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you need to write validator for the same ?set the control status to `INVALID`

Comment: @RahulSingh give me an example pls, i tried the same approach from an other question here on stackoverflow, it didnt worked for me

Comment: do you have a validator setup for you control?

Comment: @Faisal mhm i guess not, hoped i can handle it over the component and make something like `form['input.element']setInvalid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can acheive it but it is so much effort in Template driven as what you are using here.

just a gist of how you can achieve it.

Get a template reference of the form using `viewchild`.Get the form Control of the input from the ngForm and then set the `setErrors` . [LINK](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors).

Some thing like this but it is just for the input you can do it for the whole form.

```
<input #model="ngModel" [ngModel]="value">
<button (click)="model.control.setErrors({})">Invalidate</button>
```

Comment: I already knew that, but this is not my approach on this topic for the moment

Comment: @sHamann what is your approach  then . without validator you cannot set the form as invalid . that is the reason validators are there for. your case might be possible with reactive forms but not with template driven forms [might be not sure ]

Comment: since you can do something like this `voucherCode.errors?.pattern` im pretty sure you can somehow set an element of an form invalid

Comment: I dont think so i researched but this is the only way according to me @sHamann